# Send POST request and fetch data with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, request, fetch

I've been struggling with sending a POST request and fetching data back using Node.js

I've been trialing like this

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var http = require('http');

var postData = querystring.stringify({

});

var options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': postData.length
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
  res.on('end', function() {
    console.log('No more data in response.')
  })
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

But I'm stuck in `postData` and don't know what would do. Please help me. How can I fill a form in a web, then request POST method (in this case, click Search button on Google), and then fetch data responded?

Answer (score 0):

Google search doesn't use POST method while searching, it uses GET method.
You'll have to change method to GET, remove postData and embed data to be sent in url itself.

```
var options = {
    hostname: 'www.google.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/#q'+search_key, //search_key is term to be searched
    method: 'GET'
};
```

Or you can use like this also

```
http.get("http://www.google.com/#q="+search_key, function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```